# Approximation Error in a Finite Difference Approximation of the Square of Derivative

Tags: pde, finite-difference, discretization, numerics, optimal-control

First Part: (First-order derivative)

Assuming $f$ is an infinitely differential function everywhere, the Taylor series of $f(x + h)$ at $x$ is 
\begin{align}\tag{1}
f(x + h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{1}{2}h^2f''(\xi)
\end{align}
where $\xi$ is a number between $x$ and $x+h$.

After rearrangment of terms in (1), we can write
$$
f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - \frac{1}{2}hf''(\xi).
$$

Now, we define a finite difference approximation of $f'(x)$ by
$$
f'_h(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h},
$$ and we express
$$
f'(x) = f'_h(x) + E_1
$$
where approximation error $E_1$ satisfy
\begin{align}
|E_1| &= |- 0.5 hf''(\xi)| \\
    &\leq Ch
\end{align}
assuming $|- 0.5f''(\xi)| \leq C$. Now, using the definition of Big-O notation, we can say
\begin{align}\tag{2}
f'(x) = f'_h(x) + O(h)
\end{align}

This is a very standard result. However, I have a question for clarification.

Question 1:
It seems that the constant $C$ can be based on the local behavior of function between $x$ and $x+h$. Can I say that $C$ depends on $h$? Moreover, can I comment on the behavior of $C$ as $h \to 0$?

Second Part: (Square of the first-order derivative)

Using (2), the square of $f'(x)$ can be expressed as
$$
\Big(f'(x)\Big)^2 = \Big(f'_h(x) + O(h)\Big)^2
= \Big(f'_h(x)\Big)^2 + 2f'_h(x)O(h) + O(h^2) = \Big(f'_h(x)\Big)^2 + E_2
$$
where the approximation error $E_2$ is
$$
E_2 = 2f'_h(x)O(h) + O(h^2).
$$
It seems that, $E_2$ depends on the local approximation quantity $f'_h(x)$.

Question 2:
How can we estimate the leading order term for the error $E_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is true that $C$ depends on $x$ and $h$. This implies that if your function has a very poorly behaved second derivative at $x$, this method will be inaccurate. The dependance on $h$ is also to be expected, since finite differences are based on Taylor series, which converge locally, so our error estimate essentially depends on how well a Taylor series works out to $x+h$, which is where that dependency comes from. To your second part of the question, as $h\to0$, we have that if $\xi_h\in[x,x_h]$ $\forall h$, then $\xi_h\to x$. If $u$ is $C^2$, then we can say that $u''(\xi)\to u''(x)$ as $h\to 0$.
2. For this, this really is the best you can do by simply squaring the forward difference derivative. Try it for yourself on something like $x^2$ vs. $1000x^2$ at $x=0$ vs. $x=1,10,20$. At $x=0$, $f'(x)=0$ so you actually get second order convergence. As you increase $x$, your will get first order convergence at each $x$, but the prefactor of $f'(x)$ gets larger and the results will be worse and worse. $1000x^2$ will also do worse at every point because the derivative and second derivative are larger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "as $h\to0$, we have that if $\xi_h\in[x,x_h]$ $\forall h$, then $\xi_h\to x$. If $u$ is $C^2$, then we can say that $u''(\xi)\to u''(x)$ as $h\to 0$." - How can we prove this statement? Is this is a standard well-known result? If yes, where can I find it?

Comment: It is a combination of 2 results. The first is a property of nested intervals which ensures that $\xi_n\to x$ this is easily proved by contradiction. The second is just putting this limit inside the function $u''$, which we can do if $u''$ is continuous, or equivalently, is $u$ is $C^2$. This can be proven from your favorite definition of continuity and is equivalent to any of them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look into it more. I have a followup question. The approximation error (ℎ) implies that error decays linearly as ℎ→0. Does it mean that I can expect linear behavior only near to zero not otherwise? I mean, I should expect sublinear error performance far from zero, i.e. when ℎ is large.

Comment: Quadratic at 0, linear everywhere else